# Android Abort Uploading Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: android, amazon-s3

Do anyone know that how to Abort File Uploading for an Amazon S3 Bucket.
i'm using following code to Upload a file.

```
transferManager = new TransferManager(amazonClient);
upload = transferManager.upload(BUCKET_NAME, FILE_NAME, file);
try {

upload.addProgressListener(listner);    
upload.waitForUploadResult();
AppLog.logString("Unable to upload file, upload was aborted");                         

} 
catch (AmazonClientException amazonClientException) {
        System.out.println("Unable to upload file, upload was aborted.");
        amazonClientException.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is roughly how I do it. You will need to adapt it for your scenario, of course.

```
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, key, file);

    request.setProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
        public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent) {
             if (aborted.get()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Aborted");
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        PutObjectResult result = s3.putObject(request);
    } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
       // Handle exception 
    }
```

Set `aborted` to true to stop upload. You will need to recognize your exception in `catch`.

Comment: Progress Bar Stops.. 
but the File uploads in Background without showing Progress

Comment: It works for me. How do you determine that file is still being transferred?

Comment: It was Uploading in Backgorund... I'm able to achieve this by implementing LOW LEVEL UPLOADING API<br/>http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?mpListPartsJavaAPI.html