# Amazon S3 - How to abort uploading a video

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, amazon-s3

I am building an application in which a user can upload a video to Amazon S3. I am uploading the video through browser.

Here is my form for uploading:

```
<form action="FormAction" method="FormMethod" enctype="FormEnclosureType" >

                     <input id="file-upload-form-key" type="hidden" name="key" value="FileId" /> 
                     <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="AWSAccessKey" /> 
                     <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="Acl" />  
                     <input id="file-upload-form-policy" type="hidden" name="policy" value="Base64EncodedPolicy" /> 
                     <input id="file-upload-form-signature" type="hidden" name="signature" value="Signature" /> 
                     <input id="file-upload-form-redirect-url" type="hidden" name="redirect" value="RedirectUrl" /> 
                     <div class="row">
                            <label for="Title" style="padding-right: 5px;">Title (optional) </label>
                            <input id="file-upload-form-title" type="text" name="x-ignore-Title"  style="width: 200px;" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="row_clear"></div>
                     <div class="row">
                             <input id="file-upload-form-file" type="file" accept="video/*" name="file" size="100" id="file"/> 
                     </div>
               </form>
```

I want to implement a cancel button through which a user can abort the uploading. Any help on how this can be done ?

I found this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326962/android-abort-uploading-amazon-s3-bucket) which is similar to my problem. But the solution they have provided is for aborting multipart upload. Also I am not sure if this works when you are directly uploading from the browser.